# How to efficiently search a list of objects with a DateTime property in my scenario

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an already sorted list of object (sorted by date)

```
public class HistoryValue{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
   public decimal Value {get;set;
}
```

Then I have a list of days, for example,

> 1MonthAgo, 2MonthAgo,3MonthAgo,120MonthAgo

What I need is to find the Value on date

> 1MonthAgo, 2MonthAgo,3MonthAgo,120MonthAgo

If the date can not be found in the list, I should return the one just before that date. It is easiest to explain in a SQL statement although I am doing the real work in c#:

```
select top 1 Value 
   from HistoryValueList
     where Date between @d12m-@lookbackdaymax and @d12m order by Date desc
```

I was thinking of using binary search, but don't think binary search will do exactly what I want. Maybe it is best do a looping and remember the closet object of each?

Comment: `but don't think binary search will do exactly what I want` Why wouldn't it?

Comment: hi, as if the date is not in the list, I will need to find the closest one next to it. Will binary search do that for me efficiently? not sure.

Comment: So then try it and find out.  Don't just *assume* it won't work.

Comment: have you checked the efficiency against any other search algorithms?

Comment: @Servy I read through the algorithm of binary search, and don't believe the default c# implementation will do my job (will have to be some custom implementation). If you really think the default implementation will work, please prove.

Comment: @daxu Why don't you believe it will work?  By the way there are a million implementation of a binary search out there, if you simply want to know how to write your own, so you don't need a new question for that either, if you actually can't use the .NET implementation.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a "lower bound" kind of algorithm (please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389065/difference-between-basic-binary-search-for-upper-bound-and-lower-bound)), that is, a binary search (or bisect) algorithm that finds the left most element less than or equal to your search element.

Comment: think you are about right. I implemented my own binary search with memory of shortest path now. @wilfredo

Answer (score -2):

You're in luck, there is such a thing called [Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) which lets you run queries on objects in C# which implement `IEnumerable`. That includes the `List<HistoryValue>` you're using.

You're looking for some code like:

```
HistoryValue val = historyValues.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Date > dateMin && v.Date <= dateMax);
```

Where `historyValues` is your list object.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find an efficient algorithm, not just a where clause or linq query

Comment: @BijanRafraf You don't need to reinvent any wheels to use a more efficient searching algorithm.

Comment: Fair enough, his question gave me the impression he didn't know this was possible.

Comment: @ Bijan Rafraf, you just need to read the question first before posting an answer.

Comment: Out of interest, did you find a more efficient algorithm?

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty easy in C#. I am supposing that you get all records in list of HistoryValue class from DB!

Then you will write code like this:

```
List<HistoryValue> list = list;  //your list get from db here!
HistoryValue historyValue = list.Where(m=>m.Date >= @12m && m.Date <= @lookbackdaymax ).First();
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find an efficient algorithm, not just a where clause

Comment: You asked C# alternative of you SQL commad! didn't you?

Comment: @IsmailAsghar The question asked how to do so *efficiently*.  You've provided a very inefficient solution.